# Duplicate Linked with Boolean Modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, 3d-printing

I am building a model with sockets for a 3D print and want to attach various things to the finished print. To make sure that my sockets are spaced out properly I want to show them populated in the viewport on demand:

empty:
[image: empty socket]

filled:
[image: populated socket]

desired behavior: [image]

There will be a lot of sockets with different positions/rotations and I may want to modify them in batches. So I tried using Linked Duplicates for the sockets. The problem with that is that only the socket is duplicated, the Boolean Modifiers Object stays in place.

How can I show my sockets populated and also easily switch off the simulation?
Boolean modifiers are already not very good since I will have 30-40 sockets where I would manually turn on and off the *display in viewport*  option. Placing and rotating the objects manually is even worse, but would allow me to group the objects and hide them all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could parent the object + boolean object to an empty and then duplicate the whole thing but there's a problem, you can't apply a modifier to an object that is linked-duplicated, you first need to make it single user and that will slow down your work.

What you could do though is use **collection instances** rather than linked duplications. That way you can work as much as you want on your original object, and when you want you can apply its modifier, it will be applied to all its duplications.

When you're definitely good you can make the instances real, select them all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instance Real*. The objects will still share the same mesh, if you don't want that go into the header menu > *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out and get back to you!

Comment: This is quite useful, thanks! It even works recursively ;)